# C++ Compile code on Mac OS X and run it on Linux x86

Tags: c++, linux, macos, cross-compiling

I am working on a simulator, which I coded on my `Mac OS 10.6` using `XCode`, and the `Boost` library. I want to run it on my university server (some `Linux Red Hat x86`), but when running the executable produced by XCode on the server: "`./simulator: Exec format error. Wrong Architecture`." is displayed.

I cannot compile my code on the server, because Boost is not installed and I do not have the right to install it.

How can I generate an executable that would run on this Linux server? Using XCode, or command lines?

NB: I can run my code on my computer, but it would be so much faster on the server.

Comment: It's often good to native compile - build it on the server. The server has a different architecture, and you need to compile under that architecture.

Comment: You need a cross-compiler. The usual prerequisite for building one is a sacrificial virgin. It's possible but for any sort of university work this is a **massive** tangent - it's probably easier to just change your program to only use libraries available in the target environment.

Comment: Also, since Boost libraries are mostly header-only, couldn't you include their source code in your project and build it on the uni machine that way? As in, there's no reason why they need to be *installed* on the target machine.

Comment: What you can do if you are masochistic is to compile for OS X, then [run the OS X binary on Linux](https://github.com/shinh/maloader).

Comment: @millimoose Yes, it is a possibility. I am on a time-crush and I don't know the implementation details of Boost well enough to try it though. It seems very easy to miss a dependency. 

I guess I'll just use my eyes and cry...

Comment: I never worked with Boost but if you can copy files to the server, why can't you copy boost to your folder and use it to include headers or link statically against libs or whatever needs to be done. gcc for instance has `-I` for additional include folders.

Comment: Because Boost needs to be built and installed? Would it actually be possible to simply copy the files? Does anyone has done this before?

Comment: @Bibi541 Most of Boost [needs no such thing](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries) - you just need the header files on the include path. As for dependencies, just include everything in your project if you're in a hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install Boost in order to use it; especially if you're using Boost libraries that are entirely contained in header files, which is the majority of Boost's libraries. You only need to include those Boost headers with your source code and it should compile just fine.

For an easy way to bundle the needed Boost headers together with your source code, have a look at Boost's [BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) tool.

Comment: Yes, I did this and it runs just fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you're feeling moderately adventurous you could install a VM such as virtualbox, install the same version of Linux in the VM and you'll have the full capability to install any packages you want.  Build an executable in your VM and run it on your school server.

Just make sure you match the version of RH and the compiler and C/C++ libraries or your executable might not run

Answer (score 0):

You need to "cross compile". i.e. Build a linux exe on a different platform.

Some compilers will do it - others won't. Not sure about Mac ones.

As others have said: if your compiler won't cross compile to linux, doing it all in a VM is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: You could install a redhat Vm and build in there. Good point.

Comment: Installing RedHat is expensive. Literally.

Comment: No it isn't.  You can download the ISO from the web and use for free.  You just don't get support

Comment: Or use a Red Hat-alike such as Fedora, CentOS, Scientific Linux…